# Random variable convergence

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_1, \ldots,X_n,\ldots$ be independent random variable of the same normal distribution $N(7,3^2)$. Let $\hat{F}(t)$ be empirical cdf based on variables $x_1, \ldots , x_n$ in a point $t$.

Given $n \rightarrow \infty$ random variable $(\hat{F}(7)-0.5)\sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution to what?

I am completly lost with this question.

Question still remaing unanswered

**EDIT:**
Does it converge to $N(0,(3n)^2)$?

Comment: Use Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: I think i am going to need a bit more help here

Comment: $\hat F(7)$ is a m.l.e. of $\mathbb{P}(X \leq 7)$, which is $0.5$ in this case. Does this help?

Comment: It converges to $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from Wikipedia:

> Suppose $\{Y_1, Y_2, \ldots\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random
>   variables with $E[Y_i] = \mu$ and $\textrm{Var}[Y_i] = \sigma^2<\infty$. Then as $n$ approaches infinity, the random
>   variables $\sqrt{n}(S_n − \mu)$ converge in distribution to a normal
>   $N(0,\sigma^2)$:
>   $$ \sqrt {n} \left(\left({\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n} Y_{i}\right)-\mu \right)\ {\xrightarrow {d}}\ N\left(0,\sigma ^{2}\right) $$

Now take a look at your situation. How can you fit your empirical CDF into this setup? Here's what the empirical CDF based on your sample $\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$ is defined as:

$$ \hat{F}(t) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}\{X_i \leq t\} $$

Looks suspiciously like the display above, huh? So try setting $Y_i = \mathbb{1}\{X_i \leq t\}$ and see what you get.

Comment: Thus converges to $N(0,3^2)$?

Comment: No. Be careful. What is $\sigma^2$ the variance of?

Comment: Variance of a sum of each of those variables $3/n$ or rather $3n$ then? I am not sure.

Comment: $\sigma^2$ the variance of a single $Y_i$ random variable. Which, in your case, is what?

Comment: In my case $3^2$ as they are all from $N(7,3^2)$

Comment: @Mrowkacala: Put a bit more thought into this as someone is trying to help you think through this. Look at the suggested $Y_i$. It has an indicator function, which means $Y_i$ takes only two values 1 or 0 depending on the condition inside. That is, $Y_i$ is a Bernoulli.